# Is the running Xen Suse OS just Dom0?

Tags: linux, opensuse, virtual-machine, suse, xen

When I select "`Xen`" option during `Suse` boot which has installed "`Xen`" tools:
[image]

[image]
Is the running OS just `Dom0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Simon's [comment](https://forums.suse.com/showthread.php?6921-Is-the-running-Xen-Suse-OS-just-Dom0) in Suse forum, the answer is "yes": `Dom0` is the domain started by the `Xen` hypervisor on boot.